# Facebook login in ASP.Net 4.0 without MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, facebook

I want a simple FB login for my ASP.Net 4.0 website and on successful log in retrieve userid, username and user's friends list and store them in sql server DB?

Any kind of help really appreciated?

Comment: If you're not using MVC you will need to use OAUTH which is probably what facebook uses to log people in.  See http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Facebook SDK for .NET](http://facebooksdk.net/)

Comment: Is the Facebook SDK built-in in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Having your solution opened in Visual Studio 2013, go to Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages... Type *facebook* into the search field and install the Facebook SDK (should be first in the search results).

Comment: I was able to login with facebook credentials in my application. However, i want more user info from Facebook and I know I will have to use graph api, but that requires access token from FB. There are a tons of examples of how to get the access token using MVC but I could not find one example that shows how to do it using Web forms. Let me know if you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: And how is it different? This guy uses WebForms as well, check his tutorial [here](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html).